# The Realtor-duck: Encapsulating Fields with Properties

Tags: c#, meta-programming, rubberduck

The latest new refactoring for our friend Rubberduck is *Encapsulate Field*:

[image]

This image, for the sake of brevity, shows the result of the refactoring and the UI together. The three properties below the field are what is inserted by it.

All together, I am pretty satisfied with the code, so I need you to inspect it and help me improve it.

First comes the model. This class contains all the data given from the view that I need to properly create the refactoring:

```
public class EncapsulateFieldModel
{
    private readonly IList<Declaration> _declarations;

    public Declaration TargetDeclaration { get; private set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public bool ImplementLetSetterType { get; set; }
    public bool ImplementSetSetterType { get; set; }

    public EncapsulateFieldModel(RubberduckParserState parseResult, QualifiedSelection selection)
    {
        _declarations = parseResult.AllDeclarations.Where(d => !d.IsBuiltIn && d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Variable).ToList();

        TargetDeclaration = FindSelection(selection);
    }

    public Selection GetVariableStmtContextSelection(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = GetVariableStmtContext(target);

        return new Selection(statement.Start.Line, statement.Start.Column,
                statement.Stop.Line, statement.Stop.Column);
    }

    public VBAParser.VariableStmtContext GetVariableStmtContext(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = target.Context.Parent.Parent as VBAParser.VariableStmtContext;
        if (statement == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Statement not found");
        }

        return statement;
    }

    public bool HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = target.Context.Parent as VBAParser.VariableListStmtContext;

        return statement != null && statement.children.Count(i => i is VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext) > 1;
    }

    private Declaration FindSelection(QualifiedSelection selection)
    {
        var target = _declarations
            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsSelected(selection) || item.References.Any(r => r.IsSelected(selection)));

        if (target != null) { return target; }

        var targets = _declarations.Where(item => item.ComponentName == selection.QualifiedName.ComponentName);

        foreach (var declaration in targets)
        {
            var declarationSelection = new Selection(declaration.Context.Start.Line,
                                                declaration.Context.Start.Column,
                                                declaration.Context.Stop.Line,
                                                declaration.Context.Stop.Column + declaration.Context.Stop.Text.Length);

            if (declarationSelection.Contains(selection.Selection) ||
                !HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(declaration) && GetVariableStmtContextSelection(declaration).Contains(selection.Selection))
            {
                return declaration;
            }

            var reference =
                declaration.References.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));

            if (reference != null)
            {
                return reference.Declaration;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Yes, I know that the `FindSelection(QualifiedSelection)` method and its support methods have been repeated in my last three refactorings.  This will be moved to a single location later after a few more refactorings are implemented to find other patterns.

The presenter and presenter interface are next:

```
public interface IEncapsulateFieldPresenter
{
    EncapsulateFieldModel Show();
}

public class EncapsulateFieldPresenter : IEncapsulateFieldPresenter
{
    private readonly IEncapsulateFieldView _view;
    private readonly EncapsulateFieldModel _model;

    public EncapsulateFieldPresenter(IEncapsulateFieldView view, EncapsulateFieldModel model)
    {
        _view = view;
        _model = model;
    }

    private static readonly string[] PrimitiveTypes =
    {
        Tokens.Boolean,
        Tokens.Byte,
        Tokens.Date,
        Tokens.Decimal,
        Tokens.Double,
        Tokens.Long,
        Tokens.LongLong,
        Tokens.LongPtr,
        Tokens.Integer,
        Tokens.Single,
        Tokens.String,
        Tokens.StrPtr
    };

    public EncapsulateFieldModel Show()
    {
        if (_model.TargetDeclaration == null) { return null; }

        _view.NewPropertyName = _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName;
        _view.TargetDeclaration = _model.TargetDeclaration;

        if (PrimitiveTypes.Contains(_model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName))
        {
            _view.ImplementLetSetterType = true;
            _view.IsSetterTypeChangeable = false;
        }
        else if (_model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName != Tokens.Variant)
        {
            _view.ImplementSetSetterType = true;
            _view.IsSetterTypeChangeable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _view.ImplementLetSetterType = true;
        }

        if (_view.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return null;
        }

        _model.PropertyName = _view.NewPropertyName;
        _model.ImplementLetSetterType = _view.ImplementLetSetterType;
        _model.ImplementSetSetterType = _view.ImplementSetSetterType;

        _model.ParameterName = _view.ParameterName;
        return _model;
    }
}
```

Also, the presenter factory, for completeness:

```
public class EncapsulateFieldPresenterFactory : IRefactoringPresenterFactory<EncapsulateFieldPresenter>
{
    private readonly IActiveCodePaneEditor _editor;
    private readonly IEncapsulateFieldView _view;
    private readonly RubberduckParserState _parseResult;

    public EncapsulateFieldPresenterFactory(RubberduckParserState parseResult, IActiveCodePaneEditor editor, IEncapsulateFieldView view)
    {
        _editor = editor;
        _view = view;
        _parseResult = parseResult;
    }

    public EncapsulateFieldPresenter Create()
    {
        var selection = _editor.GetSelection();
        if (selection == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var model = new EncapsulateFieldModel(_parseResult, selection.Value);
        return new EncapsulateFieldPresenter(_view, model);
    }
}
```

The dialog interface:

```
public interface IEncapsulateFieldView :IDialogView
{
    Declaration TargetDeclaration { get; set; }

    string NewPropertyName { get; set; }
    bool IsSetterTypeChangeable { get; set; }

    bool ImplementLetSetterType { get; set; }
    bool ImplementSetSetterType { get; set; }

    string ParameterName { get; set; }
}
```

And the dialog code-behind:

```
public partial class EncapsulateFieldDialog : Form, IEncapsulateFieldView
{
    public string NewPropertyName
    {
        get { return PropertyNameTextBox.Text; }
        set { PropertyNameTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string ParameterName
    {
        get { return ParameterNameTextBox.Text; }
        set { ParameterNameTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public Declaration TargetDeclaration { get; set; }

    public bool ImplementLetSetterType
    {
        get { return LetSetterTypeCheckBox.Checked; }
        set { LetSetterTypeCheckBox.Checked = value; }
    }

    public bool ImplementSetSetterType
    {
        get { return SetSetterTypeCheckBox.Checked; }
        set { SetSetterTypeCheckBox.Checked = value; }
    }

    public bool IsSetterTypeChangeable
    {
        get { return SetterTypeGroupBox.Enabled; }
        set { SetterTypeGroupBox.Enabled = value; }
    }

    public EncapsulateFieldDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LocalizeDialog();

        PropertyNameTextBox.TextChanged += PropertyNameBox_TextChanged;
        ParameterNameTextBox.TextChanged += VariableNameBox_TextChanged;

        LetSetterTypeCheckBox.CheckedChanged += EncapsulateFieldDialog_SetterTypeChanged;
        SetSetterTypeCheckBox.CheckedChanged += EncapsulateFieldDialog_SetterTypeChanged;

        Shown += EncapsulateFieldDialog_Shown;
    }

    void EncapsulateFieldDialog_SetterTypeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePreview();
    }

    private void LocalizeDialog()
    {
        Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_Caption;
        TitleLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_TitleText;
        InstructionsLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_InstructionText;
        PropertyNameLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_PropertyName;
        SetterTypeGroupBox.Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_SetterType;
        VariableNameLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.EncapsulateField_ParameterName;
        OkButton.Text = RubberduckUI.OK;
        CancelDialogButton.Text = RubberduckUI.CancelButtonText;
    }

    void EncapsulateFieldDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidatePropertyName();
        ValidateVariableName();
        UpdatePreview();
    }

    private void PropertyNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidatePropertyName();
        UpdatePreview();
    }

    private void VariableNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateVariableName();
        UpdatePreview();
    }

    private void UpdatePreview()
    {
        if (TargetDeclaration == null) { return; }

        var getterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format("Public Property Get {0}() As {1}", NewPropertyName, TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", NewPropertyName, TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName),
            "End Property");

        var letterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Public Property Let {0}(ByVal {1} As {2})",
                NewPropertyName, ParameterName, TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName, ParameterName),
            "End Property");

        var setterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Public Property Set {0}(ByVal {1} As {2})",
                NewPropertyName, ParameterName, TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName, ParameterName),
            "End Property");

        PreviewBox.Text = getterText +
                          (ImplementLetSetterType ? letterText : string.Empty) +
                          (ImplementSetSetterType ? setterText : string.Empty);
    }

    private void ValidatePropertyName()
    {
        InvalidPropertyNameIcon.Visible = ValidateName(NewPropertyName, ParameterName);

        SetOkButtonEnabledState();
    }

    private void ValidateVariableName()
    {
        InvalidVariableNameIcon.Visible = ValidateName(ParameterName, NewPropertyName);

        SetOkButtonEnabledState();
    }

    private bool ValidateName(string changedName, string otherName)
    {
        var tokenValues = typeof(Tokens).GetFields().Select(item => item.GetValue(null)).Cast<string>().Select(item => item);

        return TargetDeclaration == null
                           || changedName == TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName
                           || changedName == otherName
                           || !char.IsLetter(changedName.FirstOrDefault())
                           || tokenValues.Contains(ParameterName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                           || changedName.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) && c != '_');
    }

    private void SetOkButtonEnabledState()
    {
        OkButton.Enabled = !InvalidPropertyNameIcon.Visible && !InvalidVariableNameIcon.Visible;
    }
}
```

Finally, the refactoring itself:

```
class EncapsulateFieldRefactoring : IRefactoring
{
    private readonly IRefactoringPresenterFactory<IEncapsulateFieldPresenter> _factory;
    private readonly IActiveCodePaneEditor _editor;
    private EncapsulateFieldModel _model;

    public EncapsulateFieldRefactoring(IRefactoringPresenterFactory<IEncapsulateFieldPresenter> factory, IActiveCodePaneEditor editor)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _editor = editor;
    }

    public void Refactor()
    {
        var presenter = _factory.Create();
        if (presenter == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _model = presenter.Show();

        if (_model == null) { return; }

        AddProperty();
    }

    public void Refactor(QualifiedSelection target)
    {
        Refactor();
    }

    public void Refactor(Declaration target)
    {
        Refactor();
    }

    private void AddProperty()
    {
        UpdateReferences();

        var module = _model.TargetDeclaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;
        SetFieldToPrivate(module);

        module.InsertLines(module.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1, GetPropertyText());
    }

    private void UpdateReferences()
    {
        foreach (var reference in _model.TargetDeclaration.References)
        {
            var module = reference.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

            var oldLine = module.Lines[reference.Selection.StartLine, 1];
            oldLine = oldLine.Remove(reference.Selection.StartColumn - 1, reference.Selection.EndColumn - reference.Selection.StartColumn);
            var newLine = oldLine.Insert(reference.Selection.StartColumn - 1, _model.PropertyName);

            module.ReplaceLine(reference.Selection.StartLine, newLine);
        }
    }

    private void SetFieldToPrivate(CodeModule module)
    {
        if (_model.TargetDeclaration.Accessibility == Accessibility.Private)
        {
            return;
        }

        RemoveField(_model.TargetDeclaration);

        var newField = "Private " + _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName + " As " +
                       _model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName;

        module.InsertLines(module.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1, newField);

        _editor.SetSelection(_model.TargetDeclaration.QualifiedSelection);
        for (var index = 1; index <= module.CountOfDeclarationLines; index++)
        {
            if (module.Lines[index, 1].Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                _editor.DeleteLines(new Selection(index, 0, index, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    private void RemoveField(Declaration target)
    {
        Selection selection;
        var declarationText = target.Context.GetText();
        var multipleDeclarations = _model.HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(target);

        var variableStmtContext = _model.GetVariableStmtContext(target);

        if (!multipleDeclarations)
        {
            declarationText = variableStmtContext.GetText();
            selection = _model.GetVariableStmtContextSelection(target);
        }
        else
        {
            selection = new Selection(target.Context.Start.Line, target.Context.Start.Column,
                target.Context.Stop.Line, target.Context.Stop.Column);
        }

        var oldLines = _editor.GetLines(selection);

        var newLines = oldLines.Replace(" _" + Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)
            .Remove(selection.StartColumn, declarationText.Length);

        if (multipleDeclarations)
        {
            selection = _model.GetVariableStmtContextSelection(target);
            newLines = RemoveExtraComma(_editor.GetLines(selection).Replace(oldLines, newLines));
        }

        _editor.DeleteLines(selection);

        if (newLines.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            _editor.InsertLines(selection.StartLine, newLines);
        }
    }

    private string RemoveExtraComma(string str)
    {
        if (str.Count(c => c == ',') == 1)
        {
            return str.Remove(str.IndexOf(','), 1);
        }

        var significantCharacterAfterComma = false;

        for (var index = str.IndexOf("Dim", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            if (!significantCharacterAfterComma && str[index] == ',')
            {
                return str.Remove(index, 1);
            }

            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(str[index]) && str[index] != '_' && str[index] != ',')
            {
                significantCharacterAfterComma = true;
            }

            if (str[index] == ',')
            {
                significantCharacterAfterComma = false;
            }
        }

        return str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
    }

    private string GetPropertyText()
    {
        var getterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format(Environment.NewLine + "Public Property Get {0}() As {1}", _model.PropertyName,
                _model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", _model.PropertyName, _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName),
            "End Property");

        var letterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format(Environment.NewLine + "Public Property Let {0}(ByVal {1} As {2})",
                _model.PropertyName, _model.ParameterName, _model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName, _model.ParameterName),
            "End Property");

        var setterText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            string.Format(Environment.NewLine + "Public Property Set {0}(ByVal {1} As {2})",
                _model.PropertyName, _model.ParameterName, _model.TargetDeclaration.AsTypeName),
            string.Format("    {0} = {1}", _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName, _model.ParameterName),
            "End Property");

        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                    getterText,
                    (_model.ImplementLetSetterType ? letterText : string.Empty),
                    (_model.ImplementSetSetterType ? setterText : string.Empty)).TrimEnd();
    }
}
```

Yes, I know that I have been told to not call `Refactor()` from the `Refactor(QualifiedSelection)` and `Refactor(Declaration)` methods, but I felt it was justified here because I have to show the UI anyway, and this way, I could keep duplication of logic down.

I have done my best writing this code, now it is up to you to do your best to tear the bad sections apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor for now:

Throwing a `NullReferenceException` in `GetVariableStmtContext` seems not quite right. Even without the check you code would not throw this exception. I would argue an `ArgumentException` or maybe some custom `InvalidParseStateException` might be more appropriate.

**Update**: A few more:

- I'm inclined to go with Jon Skeet in terms of [a factory method called `Create` shouldn't return `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124581/220986) (in `EncapsulateFieldPresenterFactory`).
- I'm not convinced that the validation should live in the view - the view should be presenting the data (including validation results) but not the actual business logic for it.
- In `UpdateReferences` some local variables could improve readability:

  ```
      var beginning = reference.Selection.StartColumn - 1;
      var length = reference.Selection.EndColumn - beginning + 1;
      oldLine = oldLine.Remove(beginning, length);
      var newLine = oldLine.Insert(beginning, _model.PropertyName);
  ```
- Things like these `target.Context.Start.Line` are a bit of a code smell (deep call chains introduce additional dependencies) although I have no immediate remedy on how to refactor this better right now.